# How can I create a new object every pass through a loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object

I'm doing a project where there may be any number of objects that I might need to create and I'll never know for sure exactly how many I have to make.

What I want to do is create a new object every time there is a new pass through this loop. Then it will immediately add it to the arrayList called list.

```
for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {
    GradeInfo person(x) = new GradeInfo();
    list.add(person(x));

    list.get(x).setStudentID(inputFile.nextInt());
    inputFile.nextLine();
    list.get(x).setFullName(inputFile.nextLine());
    testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
    list.get(x).setTestScore(testScore);
    list.get(x).setGrade(testScore);
    averageScore = averageScore + testScore;

}
```

The above is my attempt at making a new object every time it passes the loop, but it isn't working.

The ideal scenario would be

```
GradeInfo person1 = new GradeInfo();
list.add(person1);
```

that this occurs and happens for how ever many times it goes through the loop, in my case it would create 10 person objects. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What isn't working about your code? Do you get any error messages or compiler warnings, or does it just give you different results than you're expecting?

Comment: Try to remove the (x) from the new referance name. You could just keep the objects with the same name et identify them by their place in the List.

Comment: It's not a good idea to add elements to a list that you are iterating through. Specifically, `x < list.size()` will never fail because `list.add(person(x));` adds one more element to list each time through the loop.

Comment: Person is an object created for each individual student.

Comment: Good point @Don I'll have to move the new object created out of this loop. I see the error on that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your posted example compile? This syntax is not valid Java:

```
GradeInfo person(x) = new GradeInfo();
```

It looks like you are mixing in a bit of C++. You've got the right idea, though: to create a new object at each iteration of a loop...simply create a new object at each iteration of the loop!

```
for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)
{
    GradeInfo person = new GradeInfo();
    list.add(person);
    ...
}
```

However, it is not wise to add to the list you are currently iterating over, especially with the way you are evaluating your for loop's end condition. The way this is written, each iteration will add something to your list, then at the end of the iteration `list.size()` will be called again and it will return the new size of the list. So this will actually end up being an infinite loop, because your list is constantly expanding. So you should really be working with two separate lists here: one of `GradeInfo`, and one of persons.

You also do not need to retrieve the `GradeInfo` you've just added to the list in order to work with it; you already have a reference to it, so you can act directly on the reference and you will see the changes reflected in the item you've added to the list.

```
int numPersons = personList.size();
List<GradeInfo> gradeInfos = new ArrayList<GradeInfo>();
for (int x = 0; x < numPersons; x++)
{
    GradeInfo newGradeInfo = new GradeInfo();
    gradeInfos.add(newGradeInfo);

    newGradeInfo.setStudentID(inputFile.nextInt());
    inputFile.nextLine();

    newGradeInfo.setFullName(inputFile.nextLine());

    testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
    newGradeInfo.setTestScore(testScore);
    newGradeInfo.setGrade(testScore);

    averageScore = averageScore + testScore;
}
```

You will end up with a list of distinct `GradeInfo` objects. If you were to write a method that takes a `GradeInfo` and prints out its information, you could loop over this list and see exactly what happens.

```
for (final GradeInfo gradeInfo : gradeInfos)
{
    printInfo(gradeInfo);
}

=>
StudentID: 123
FullName: asdf asdf
TestScore: 100
Grade: 100
----------------------
StudentID: 456
FullName: michael jackson
TestScore: 23
Grade: 23
----------------------
....
```

Comment: Would this automatically create person, then person1, person2, person3 through each iteration of the loop?

Comment: @Matt I will improve my answer to provide an example of what this will produce.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful

Comment: That's awesome, what I was looking to do. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @Matt No problem, sorry for the long anwer though lol happy hacking!